# Select2 multiple: true not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I am using the select2 gem in a rails app, I can not get the form to accept multiple values, I checked the documentation and it seemed straight forward but I can not get it to work.

```
<link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="select2.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { $("#e2").select2({
    multiple:true
    });
  });
</script>
<select id="e2">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What error messages are you seeing on the javascript console in your browser, if any?  Have you included jquery in your page?

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:
"When Select2 is attached to a select element {multiple:true} will be ignored and select's multiple attribute will be used instead."

So this should work:

```
<select multiple id="e2">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Example fiddle for multiple select2:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcusasplund/sqvLx3qd/

Link to docs:
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation

Answer (score 2):

hey this will help you

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="e2">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option> 
</select>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#e2").select2({
          placeholder: "**Put Your Place Holder Here**"
      });
    }); 
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm select valid" id="UserTagsFilterValue" multiple="multiple" name="UserTagsFilterValue" aria-invalid="false">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="7">ahahah</option>
<option value="9">tag2</option>
</select>
```